# Django: qual a diferença entre importar/usar include() e não usar quando se configura uma URL?

Tags: django, url, django-templates

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Neste exemplo vi que há dois jeitos de chamar uma URL, uma com `include()` e outra sem include. Qual a diferença?

Comment: Boa pergunta +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em um sistema, podem existir centenas de urls. Fica um tanto quanto desorganizado você colocar tudo em apenas um arquivo de url.
Existe um arquivo urls.py principal que vem no mesmo diretório do settings.
O include sugere que você está trabalhando com um outro arquivo de url que possui aquele prefixo na frente.

Conforme você vai criando as suas apps, o adequado é você ter um arquivo urls.py para cada app.

Por exemplo, supondo que você crie uma app chamada produtos:

No seu urls.py principal, você teria:

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^produtos/', include('produtos.urls', namespace='produtos')),
]
```

Dentro da app produtos você poderá criar um novo arquivo urls.py com todas as urls referentes a aquela app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('produtos.views',
    url(r'^novo/$', 'produto_novo', name='produto'),
    url(r'^editar/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'editar_produto', name='editar'),
    url(r'^lista/$','lista_produtos', name='lista'),
)
```

Essas urls desse novo arquivo, poderiam estar sim apenas no arquivo urls.py principal, mas isso não é uma boa prática.
Qual é mais simples, procurar uma url em um arquivo com 30 urls ou em um arquivo que tem apenas 3 urls?

O namespace que eu coloquei no urls principal, serve para a chamada da url, por exemplo:

```
<a href="{% url 'produtos:novo' %}">Novo Produto</a>
```

Se for apenas um site institucional que esteja fazendo em django, tudo bem deixar tudo no urls principal, mas eu por exemplo, trabalho em sistemas que possuem mais de 100 urls.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara, muito bom! Entendi perfeitamente agora. Muito obrigado!